# How to create xy grid that covers entire sample area with specific number of nodes in python?

Tags: python, numpy, grid

I am looking at 2D spatial data (x,y,(z)), where z is a property of x,y not another spatial dimension. What I want to do in my application is to have the user toggle an "Number of x nodes" slider bar. The program looks at their sample data that they loaded, and, using the aspect ratio of their data, chooses the number of y nodes to have 1:1 aspect grid created over their sample.

[image: grid node select]

This part works fine. But know I need to create that actual grid data. I do this using itertools, and getting all the combinations of two arrays. One for x and one for y.

```
xnodes=#number of x from user choice
dx=(max(x)-min(x))/xnodes
grid_xy = np.array(list(itertools.product(
            np.arange(min(x),max(x),step=dx),
            np.arange(min(y),max(y),step=dx))))
```

Note that I use dx in both arrays because I want the grid aspect to be 1:1. The number of total nodes just goes to the user so that they know if it's going to take a long time to compute or not. What I get is a situation like this.

[image]

The grid nodes do not cover the whole area (as the number of x nodes gets larger, it eventually gets very close). Also, the rounding inherent in np.arange means that sometime it overshoots the sample data, which is what I want, bt sometimes undershoots. How can I make sure to capture all the sample data with my grid, while only using the number of nodes specified to the user? One solutio n I can see would be to add another row of nodes to the end of each grid columns.

Comment: have you looked at np.linspace?  np.linspace(0, 9, 5) with nodes=5
array([0.  , 2.25, 4.5 , 6.75, 9.  ]) or adding dx to np.arange …. np.arange(x.min(), x.max()+dx)

Comment: Sorry. Just had time to test this. The np.linspace worked. I didn't know that linspace worked by always including endpoints and doing the intermittent division for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was

```
self.grid_xy = np.array(list(itertools.product(
     np.linspace(self.min_gx,self.max_gx,num=self.s1.get()),
     np.linspace(self.min_gy,self.max_gy,num=self.s2.get()))))
```

or, without the class structure

```
self.grid_xy = np.array(list(itertools.product(
     np.linspace(min(x),(max(x),num=x_nodes),
     np.linspace(min(y),(max(y),num=y_nodes))))
```